# How and when to use this dienen verb?

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german, vocabulary, swiss-standard-german

[As I checked the dictionary](https://en.pons.com/translate/german-english/dienen) there are different meanings for it which are unrelatable with each other.

I came across this sentence in book:

> Neue Zeiten brechen an, denn in Zukunft können etwa zum Türöffnen menschliche Netzwerke dienen.

The translator shows: dienen as for example.

To some extent, I understand it as *dienen* replaces the *helfen* verb as a synonym, but is there a specific usage method for *dienen* with different meanings from native speaker's point of view?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, that [a translator like deepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Neue%20Zeiten%20brechen%20an%2C%20denn%20in%20Zukunft%20k%C3%B6nnen%20etwa%20zum%20T%C3%BCr%C3%B6ffnen%20menschliche%20Netzwerke%20dienen.) *includes* "for example" in the translation, but you are incorrect that this is the translation of *dienen*. In this case "for example" is a fitting translation for *etwa*. Or in other words, we can replace *etwa* with *zum Beispiel*.

> Neue Zeiten brechen an, denn in Zukunft können zum Beispiel zum Türöffnen menschliche Netzwerke dienen.

*Dienen* is very closely related to *Diener*(servant, butler). It is commonly used in a polite form (especially in customer service<sup>1</sup>) in the sense of providing a service or product (as some examples in your dictionary also show).

In the example above, *dienen* can literally be translated as *to serve*, as in

> We are entering a new era, since in the future human networks could [serve as a tool / be used] to open doors.

This is - in a way - a more fancy way of expressing the option of use/help.

<sup>1</sup>There is the saying *Der Kunde ist König* which kind of reflects to *dienen*, but some people take this way too literally.

Comment: In general, the construction seems to be *dienen* + *zum* + (nominalized verb) and translates as "to be used for (doing something)" For example *Diese Stiefel dienen zum Laufen.* -- "These boots are used for walking." (Apologies to Nancy Sinatra.) This seems to be covered under meaning 4 of the DWDS entry, but that also covers *dienen als* which to me seems like a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dienen) condenses the list to 4 simple meanings:

1. Military service (or other strongly dependent employment scheme of former times); this is seldom used since compulsory service was stopped due to the restricted scope.
2. somehow support/serve; probably the most frequently used meaning, but completely unspecific in the degree of support, which may range from "smallish contribution" to "nothing else is needed". (The unspecific nature may well be intended due to lack of knowledge.)
3. A flattering term for offering a favour, in my opinion bordering to self-humilation; I would prefer *helfen* in most cases, since it is more neutral
4. Similar to meaning 2, also frequently used, translates to *functions as*

Comment: The most relevant for the original question is #4, as I mentioned in my other comment. I'm not sure that your summary covers the meaning used in the original question though, since "functions as" doesn't really fit there.

Comment: @RDBury: Perhaps I didn't understand the original quote correctly; I don't get, how the connection of how human (=social?) networks to open doors  is made. If the non-literal *open doors* are meant, it still looks more like meaning 2.

Comment: My (perhaps uninformed) impression was that 4 covered cases with *als* or *zu* and 2 did not include those. So with 2 there has to be a cause, a goal, a group of people, etc. that the subject is aiding. With 4/*zu*, the subject is used to do something or used for something, this time represented by an abstract noun. But the main goal here is figure out what "dienen* means in the given sentence, and if my impression of the way DWDS organized its entry is wrong then I'm not overly concerned.